# AutoMapper: Mapping to private setters contained in nested objects defined by Interfaces

Tags: c#, automapper

I have created a console app that reflects the problem that I am having.
I want to :

1. Be able to map to ReadOnly properties (ones with private setters)
2. Have those properties be inside nested objects
3. Have those nested objects be declared as an Interface within their parent class

I can't seem to get all of the above at the same time. Here is the example code:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbCvg = new DbCoverage("123", "b", "blue", new DbChild(5, 9));

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<IDbCoverage, Coverage>();
                cfg.CreateMap<IDbChild, IChild>();
            });

            var mapper = new Mapper(config);

            var destClass = mapper.Map<Coverage>(dbCvg);

            Console.WriteLine(destClass.ExternalMemberId);
            Console.WriteLine(destClass.CoverageCode);
            Console.WriteLine(destClass.ReadOnlyDesc);

            Console.WriteLine(destClass.Child.someValue);
            Console.WriteLine(destClass.Child.readOnlyValue);
        }
    }

    public interface IDbCoverage
    {
        string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }
        string CoverageCode { get; set; }
        string ReadOnlyDesc { get; }
        IDbChild Child { get; set; }
    }


    public interface IDbChild
    {
        int someValue { get; set; }
        int readOnlyValue { get; }
    }

    public interface ICoverage
    {
        string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }
        string CoverageCode { get; set; }
        string ReadOnlyDesc { get; }
        IChild Child { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IChild
    {
        int someValue { get; set; }
        int readOnlyValue { get; }
    }

    public class Coverage : ICoverage
    {
        public string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }
        public string CoverageCode { get; set; }
        public string ReadOnlyDesc { get; private set; }
        public IChild Child { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Child : IChild
    {
        public int someValue { get; set; }
        public int readOnlyValue { get; private set; }
    }

    public class DbCoverage : IDbCoverage
    {
        public string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }
        public string CoverageCode { get; set; }
        public string ReadOnlyDesc { get; private set; }
        public IDbChild Child { get; set; }

        public DbCoverage(string Id, string code, string desc, IDbChild child)
        {
            ExternalMemberId = Id;
            CoverageCode = code;
            ReadOnlyDesc = desc;
            Child = child;
        }
    }

    public class DbChild : IDbChild
    {
        public int someValue { get; set; }
        public int readOnlyValue { get; private set; }

        public DbChild(int smVal, int roVal)
        {
            someValue = smVal;
            readOnlyValue = roVal;
        }
    }
}
```

When this runs we can see that the final line of output is 0 instead of 9 because the 9 was not mapped.
This is due to the fact that the Mapping is from IDbChild -> IChild and IChild does not have a setter for that property.

However, if I instead try to map IDbChild -> Child I get a compilation error which I believe is because the nested Child property in the Coverage object is defined as an Interface and so it wants an IDbChild -> IChild mapping.

Is there any way to alter the mapping configuration (**but not the underlying objects**) to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping interfaces only complicates things. But it's possible.

```
    cfg.CreateMap<IDbChild, Child>();
    cfg.CreateMap<IDbChild, IChild>().As<Child>();
```

https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying each of those lines on their own but I never put them together like that.